# How to change month input automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

I need a SQL query that will increase the month in this query based on the calendar.  When the system calendar changes to a new month, the date string in the `when` clause must change too:

```
UPDATE dbo.dim_time
SET last12 =
CASE
    WHEN date < '2012-09-01' THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END
```

This month it was `date < '2012-09-01'`.

Next month it should automatically change to `date < '2012-10-01'`.

Comment: Did you miss the year? It should be 2013?

Comment: Always first day of every month?

Answer (score 1):

If you've wrongly mention 2012 instead of 2013, then below query will do it.

```
Update dbo.dim_time
Set last12 =
Case
When date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(getdate())-1),getdate()),101)
then 'No'
Else 'Yes'
End
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update dbo.dim_time
Set last12 =
Case
WHEN date < DATEADD(M,MONTH(GETDATE()),DATEADD(YYYY,YEAR(GETDATE())-2000,'12-01-1999'))     
then 'No'
Else 'Yes'
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF`

```
Update dbo.dim_time
Set last12 = Case When DateDiff(m,date,getdate())>12 then 'No' Else 'Yes' End
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MS SQL Server 2012 you can construct a date with the following functions

- [DateFromParts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) - 
  Returns a date value for the specified year, month, and day.
- [GetDate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) - Returns the current DateTime
- [Month](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) - Returns the month part of a DateTime
- [Year](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) - Returns the year part of a DateTime

For example

```
Update dbo.dim_time
Set last12 =
Case
When date < DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate())-1, month(getdate()),1) then 'No'
Else 'Yes'
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL

```
UPDATE dbo.dim_time
SET last12 =
CASE
WHEN DATE < cast(CAST(Year(getdate()) as NVARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(Month(getdate())as NVARCHAR(10)) +'-01' as Date)
THEN 'No'
Else 'Yes'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably better using a computed column so that you don't need to continue to update every month.

```
create table #DimDate
([date] Date, last12 varchar(5))

INSERT INTO #DimDate
SELECT dateAdd(m, X.c, getdate()), 'No'
FROM  
(Values (-1),(-2),(-3),(-4),(-5),(-6),(-7),(-8),(-9),(-10),(-11),(-12),(-13),(-14),(-15),(-16))  AS X(c)


ALTER TABLE #DimDate
DROP COLUMN last12

ALTER TABLE #DimDate
ADD  last12 AS Case When DateDiff(m,date,getdate())>12 then 'No' Else 'Yes' End


SELECT *
FROM #DimDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the date string with an expression.  This expression would give you the first day of the current month:

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

Since 2012-09-01 is 34 months ago from the current month, you can calculate thirty for months prior to the start of the current month with:

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,GETDATE()) - 34, 0)
```

So your update statement would be:

```
Update dbo.dim_time
Set last12 =
Case When date < dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,GETDATE()) - 34, 0) then 
    'No'
Else 
    'Yes'
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetDate()`...the current month with date will come..From that compare your field value,if true then change else keep as it is..